# What is using so much memory on an idle linux server? Comparing output of "htop" and "ps aux"

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am trying to understand and compare the output I see from htop (sorted by mem%) and "ps aux --sort=-%mem | grep query.jar" and determine why 24.2G out of 32.3G is in use on an idle server.

The ps command shows a single parent (not child process I assume):

```
ps aux --sort=-%mem | grep query.jar
1000      67970  0.4  4.4 6721304 1452512 ?     Sl    2020 163:55 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx700m -Xss256k -jar ./query.jar
```

Whereas htop shows PID 6790 as well as many other PIDs for query.jar below.  I am trying to grasp what this means for memory usage. I also wonder if this has anything to do with open file handlers.

[image]

I ran this file handler command on the server: ls -la /proc/$$/fd
which produces this output (although I am not sure if this is showing me any issues):

```
total 0
lrwx------. 1 ziggy ziggy 64 Jan  2 09:14 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 ziggy ziggy 64 Jan  2 09:14 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 ziggy ziggy 64 Jan  2 09:14 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------. 1 ziggy ziggy 64 Jan  2 11:39 255 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------. 1 ziggy ziggy 64 Jan  2 09:14 3 -> /var/lib/sss/mc/passwd
```

Obviously the mem% output in htop (if totaled) exceeds 100% so I am guessing that despite there being different pids, the repetitive mem% values shown of 9.6 and 4.4 are not necessarily unique.  Any clarification is appreciated here.  I am trying to determine the best method to accurately report what is using 24.GB of memory on this server.

The complete output of the ps aux command is here which shows me all the different pids using memory. Again, I am confused by how this output differs form htop.

```
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1000      40268  0.2  9.5 3432116 3143516 ?     Sl    2020  73:33 /usr/local/bin/node --max-http-header-size=65000 index.js
1000      67970  0.4  4.4 6721304 1452516 ?     Sl    2020 164:05 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx700m -Xss256k -jar ./query.jar
root      86212  2.6  3.0 15208548 989928 ?     Ssl   2020 194:18 dgraph alpha --my=dgraph-public:9080 --lru_mb 2048 --zero dgraph-public:5080
1000      68027  0.2  2.9 6295452 956516 ?      Sl    2020  71:43 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx512m -Xss256k -jar ./build.jar
1000      88233  0.3  2.9 6415084 956096 ?      Sl    2020 129:25 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx500m -Xss256k -jar ./management.jar
1000      66554  0.4  2.4 6369108 803632 ?      SLl   2020 159:23 ./TranslationService thrift sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 S1
polkitd   27852  1.2  2.3 2111292 768376 ?      Ssl   2020 417:24 mongod --config /data/configdb/mongod.conf --bind_ip_all
root      52493  3.3  2.3 8361444 768188 ?      Ssl   2020 1107:53 /bin/prometheus --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries --storage.tsdb.retention.size=7G
B --config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus --storage.tsdb.retention.time=30d --web.enable-lifecycle --storage.tsdb.no-lockfile --web.external-url=http://sisense-prom-oper
ator-prom-prometheus.monitoring:9090 --web.route-prefix=/
1000      54574  0.0  1.9 901996 628900 ?       Sl    2020  13:47 /usr/local/bin/node dist/index.js
root      78245  0.9  1.9 11755696 622940 ?     Ssl   2020 325:03 /fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit -c /fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
root       5838  4.4  1.4 781420 484736 ?       Ssl   2020 1488:26 kube-apiserver --advertise-address=10.1.17.71 --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=True --apiserver-count=1 --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --bind-addre
ss=0.0.0.0 --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-aggregator-routing=False --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --endpoint-reconciler-type=lease --etcd-cafile=/etc/ssl
/etcd/ssl/ca.pem --etcd-certfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-dev-analytics-2.pem --etcd-keyfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-dev-analytics-2-key.pem --etcd-servers=https://10.1.17.71:2379 --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-client-certificat
e=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalDNS,InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP --profiling=
False --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.key --request-timeout=1m0s --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --request
header-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --runtime-config
= --secure-port=6443 --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/sa.pub --service-cluster-ip-range=10.233.0.0/18 --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 --storage-backend=etcd3 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserve
r.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.key
1000      91921  0.1  1.2 7474852 415516 ?      Sl    2020  41:04 java -Xmx4G -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djvmp -DEC2EC -cp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/jvmcontainer_1_1_0.jar com.sisense.container.launcher.ContainerLaunc
herApp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/connectors/ec2ec/com.sisense.connectors.Ec2ec.jar sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 connectors.sisense
1000      21035  0.3  0.8 2291908 290568 ?      Ssl   2020 111:23 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=. -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../build/classes:/zookeeper-
3.4.12/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../lib/log4j-1
.2.17.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.12.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/conf: -XX:MaxRA
MFraction=2 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XshowSettings:vm -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMa
in /conf/zoo.cfg
1000      91955  0.1  0.8 7323208 269844 ?      Sl    2020  40:40 java -Xmx4G -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djvmp -DGenericJDBC -cp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/jvmcontainer_1_1_0.jar com.sisense.container.launcher.Containe
rLauncherApp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/connectors/genericjdbc/com.sisense.connectors.GenericJDBC.jar sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 connectors.sisense
1000      92076  0.1  0.8 8302704 262772 ?      Sl    2020  52:11 java -Xmx4G -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djvmp -Dsql -cp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/jvmcontainer_1_1_0.jar com.sisense.container.launcher.ContainerLaunche
rApp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/connectors/mssql/com.sisense.connectors.MsSql.jar sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 connectors.sisense
1000      91800  0.1  0.7 9667560 259928 ?      Sl    2020  39:38 java -Xms128M -jar connectorService.jar jvmcontainer_1_1_0.jar /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/connectors sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 connectors.sisense
1000      91937  0.1  0.7 7326312 253708 ?      Sl    2020  40:14 java -Xmx4G -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djvmp -DExcel -cp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/jvmcontainer_1_1_0.jar com.sisense.container.launcher.ContainerLaunc
herApp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/connectors/excel/com.sisense.connectors.ExcelConnector.jar sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 connectors.sisense
1000      92085  0.1  0.7 7323660 244160 ?      Sl    2020  39:53 java -Xmx4G -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djvmp -DSalesforceJDBC -cp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/jvmcontainer_1_1_0.jar com.sisense.container.launcher.Conta
inerLauncherApp /opt/sisense/jvmConnectors/connectors/salesforce/com.sisense.connectors.Salesforce.jar sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 connectors.sisense
1000      16326  0.1  0.7 3327260 243804 ?      Sl    2020  12:21 /opt/sisense/monetdb/bin/mserver5 --zk_system_name=S1 --zk_address=sisense-zookeeper.sisense:2181 --external_server=ec-devcube-qry-10669921-96e0-4.sisense -
-instance_id=qry-10669921-96e0-4 --dbname=aDevCube --farmstate=Querying --dbfarm=/tmp/aDevCube_2020.12.28.16.46.23.280/dbfarm --set mapi_port 50000 --set gdk_nr_threads 4
100       64158 20.4  0.7 1381624 232548 ?      Sl    2020 6786:08 /usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-11.0.3/bin/beam.smp -W w -K true -A 128 -MBas ageffcbf -MHas ageffcbf -MBlmbcs 512 -MHlmbcs 512 -MMmcs 30 -P 1048576 -t 5000000
-stbt db -zdbbl 128000 -B i -- -root /usr/local/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa  -noshell -noinput -s rabbit boot -boot start_sasl -lager crash_log false -lager handlers []
root       1324 11.3  0.7 5105748 231100 ?      Ssl   2020 3773:15 /usr/bin/dockerd --iptables=false --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --dns 10.233.0.3 --dns 10.1.22.68 --dns 10.1.22.6
9 --dns-search default.svc.cluster.local --dns-search svc.cluster.local --dns-opt ndots:2 --dns-opt timeout:2 --dns-opt attempts:2
```

Adding more details:

$ free -m

```
Mem:          31993       23150        2602        1677        6240        6772
Swap:             0           0           0
```

$ top -b -n1 -o "%MEM"|head -n 20

```
top - 13:46:18 up 23 days,  3:26,  3 users,  load average: 2.26, 1.95, 2.10
Tasks: 2201 total,   1 running, 2199 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.4 us, 10.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32761536 total,  2639584 free, 23730688 used,  6391264 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  6910444 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 40268 1000      20   0 3439284   3.0g   8228 S   0.0  9.6  73:39.94 node
 67970 1000      20   0 6721304   1.4g   7216 S   0.0  4.4 164:24.16 java
 86212 root      20   0   14.5g 996184  13576 S   0.0  3.0 197:36.83 dgraph
 68027 1000      20   0 6295452 956516   7256 S   0.0  2.9  71:52.15 java
 88233 1000      20   0 6415084 956096   9556 S   0.0  2.9 129:40.80 java
 66554 1000      20   0 6385500 803636   8184 S   0.0  2.5 159:42.44 TranslationServ
 27852 polkitd   20   0 2111292 766860  11368 S   0.0  2.3 418:26.86 mongod
 52493 root      20   0 8399864 724576  15980 S   0.0  2.2   1110:34 prometheus
 54574 1000      20   0  905324 631708   7656 S   0.0  1.9  13:48.66 node
 78245 root      20   0   11.2g 623028   1800 S   0.0  1.9 325:43.74 fluent-bit
  5838 root      20   0  781420 477016  22944 S   7.7  1.5   1492:08 kube-apiserver
 91921 1000      20   0 7474852 415516   3652 S   0.0  1.3  41:10.25 java
 21035 1000      20   0 2291908 290484   3012 S   0.0  0.9 111:38.03 java
```

Comment: Firstly I wouldn't call a 4-core machine using ~ 20% of it's CPU **idle** ;) ... underutilised, sure, but not idle.  Secondly I'd like to see the output of `free -m` and/or `top -b -n1 -o "%MEM"|head -n 20` in your post.

Comment: fair enough. not idle but much memory used when the applications are simply running but not actively used.  I appended the info you mentioned to the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between `htop` and `ps aux` is that `htop` shows each individual thread belonging to a process rather than the process only - this is similar to `ps auxm`. Using the `htop` interactive command `H`, you can hide threads to get to a list that more closely corresponds to `ps aux`.

In terms of memory usage, those additional entries representing individual threads do not affect the actual memory usage total because threads share the address space of the associated process.

`RSS` (resident set size) in general is problematic because it does not adequately represent shared pages (due to shared memory or copy-on-write) for your purpose - the sum can be higher than expected in those cases. You can use `smem -t` to get a better picture with the `PSS` (proportional set size) column. Based on the facts you provided, that is not your issue, though.

In your case, it might make sense to dig deeper via `smem -tw` to get a memory usage breakdown that includes (non-cache) kernel resources. `/proc/meminfo` provides further details.